# NodeJS + Redis + Express + Passport Facebook auth fails

Tags: node.js, express, node-redis, passport-facebook

I've one problem with NodeJS and redis integration with passport facebook. This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('ejs').__express;
var app = express();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var hanzi  = require('./modules/hanzi');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport')
, FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
, RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)
, redis = require('redis')
, dbRedis = redis.createClient();

Server = mongo.Server,
Db = mongo.Db,
BSON = mongo.BSONPure;


app.configure(function () {

    var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
        client: dbRedis,
    });

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8088);
    app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
    app.engine('ejs', engine);
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
    app.use( express.cookieParser() );
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'im your besta' ,
        cookie: {secure: true, maxAge:86400000},
        store: sessionStore
    }));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
});
```

But when i log in thanks to facebook, i find the right user, use `done(null,oldUser);` but my ensureAuthenticated() function is always false...

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:**
serialize/deserialize

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
                    console.log("serialize user");
                    console.log(user._id);
                    done(null, user._id);
                });

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
                    console.log("deserialize user");
                    done(null, obj);
                });

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
                    clientID: "xxx",
                    clientSecret: "xxxx",
                    callbackURL: "http://myurl/auth/facebook/callback"
                },
                function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

                    db.collection('fbs', function(err, collection) {
                        collection.findOne({fbId : profile.id}, function(err, oldUser) {
                            if(oldUser){
                                console.log("OK");
                                console.log(oldUser);
                                done(null,oldUser);
                            }else{
                                console.log("NEW USER");
                                var newUser = new FbUsers({
                                    fbId : profile.id ,
                                    email : profile.emails[0].value,
                                    name : profile.displayName
                                }).save(function(err,newUser){
                                    if(err) throw err;
                                    done(null, newUser);
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    });
                }
                ));

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/')
}
```

**EDIT 2 : Add redis log**

```
+1395994580.698685 (db 2) "setex" "sess:Od0RD3AcyIhTMUynnlDQobEr" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:20.698Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}"
+1395994582.099713 (db 2) "setex" "sess:OT1Rht88PPbeMDnKvYjMmGlC" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.099Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.102495 (db 2) "setex" "sess:nu6Pm2xb4SFpf8IPNFz7oBUa" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.102Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.104810 (db 2) "setex" "sess:qckQqsbZsEWCrpA1dJEvRdsa" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.104Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.109756 (db 2) "setex" "sess:WmXRkw2GKWx8DRz25RIwMOWJ" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.109Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.112338 (db 2) "setex" "sess:3WkCT4YqL1mpeyHXiBwjpWpR" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.112Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.117175 (db 2) "setex" "sess:yKaQ2Z5QJaC8UG1dw2q0sZMo" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.117Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.248297 (db 2) "setex" "sess:m2xlPaDlFCnVelxFnvmWEnKJ" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.248Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.964619 (db 2) "setex" "sess:XWQeeUCS7JUZTPzxZSMxqUpR" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.964Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994582.970229 (db 2) "setex" "sess:LqgRcHrnIaXfXVceHgdZ6FlN" "86399" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86399999,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:22.969Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994588.902167 (db 2) "setex" "sess:qXO9gBrHu8vp64UyKYJHWcCq" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:28.900Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}"
+1395994590.304890 (db 2) "setex" "sess:JA4KfLN92wVIYrcOyhZeQw2O" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:30.304Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"52de69b0c432647c5fc6309c\"}}"
+1395994590.690489 (db 2) "setex" "sess:Vc6Z6oLnnxGqqzItuEWpO8ab" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:30.690Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}"
+1395994591.582708 (db 2) "setex" "sess:XIud7BMHoPjJ0BFf6AMkrJV9" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.582Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994591.585150 (db 2) "setex" "sess:IlHl8a7QDp2g9UpXAmYHOk09" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.585Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994591.631536 (db 2) "setex" "sess:jeLL5UZkPXEeK8K3mbCaBwrl" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.631Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994591.634714 (db 2) "setex" "sess:xIgC6NKShHW8ewG8YGSCm0vn" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.634Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994591.638343 (db 2) "setex" "sess:SxfiYe5TBeUGrNQ4z3MPIBHe" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.638Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994591.953461 (db 2) "setex" "sess:JK0nt4aD0ycED0kjiAEPZEPD" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.953Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994591.987201 (db 2) "setex" "sess:B6TOzQWvBo8HiN55so28iL8X" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:31.987Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994592.033600 (db 2) "setex" "sess:BoQODHZ8kjgqczNAe7By8kEs" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:32.033Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
+1395994592.036671 (db 2) "setex" "sess:lmeCXBZUr0dw38iozFNOBayK" "86400" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-29T08:16:32.036Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
```

I don't know why i add so many cookies ... Any idea?

Comment: Can you please add the passport configuration code and ensureAuthenticated() function

Comment: In `passport.deserializeUser()`, you must find the user object `user` by the user id(i.e. `obj`) and call `done(null, user);`.

Comment: But i never call deserializeUser(). I've put some log and it never appears in my node logs...

Comment: I've changed it , but it the same... And deserialzeUser is never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the serializeUser function is used by req.logIn function provided by passport.

```
req.login =
req.logIn = function(user, options, done) {
  if (typeof options == 'function') {
    done = options;
    options = {};
  }
  options = options || {};

  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {
    property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
  }
  var session = (options.session === undefined) ? true : options.session;

  this[property] = user;
  if (session) {
    if (!this._passport) { throw new Error('passport.initialize() middleware not in use'); }
    if (typeof done != 'function') { throw new Error('req#login requires a callback function'); }

    var self = this;
    this._passport.instance.serializeUser(user, this, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) { self[property] = null; return done(err); }
      self._passport.session.user = obj;
      done();
    });
  } else {
    done && done();
  }
};
```

This req.logIn function can be called to persist the serialized user in the session and thus for doing the login. This function is automatically called by passport.authenticate function, which calls it after getting the user according to the defined strategy,

Creating a passport strategy create a procedure for passport to find your user, it does not perform the login by itself. The isAuthenticated is false because the login is never happening.

So to create an auth route for your facebook authentication strategy, add something like this to your routes,

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { state: 'SOME STATE' }));
```

Now this on going to this route passport will find the user using your facebook strategy and automatically perform the login for this user.

Assuming your facebook stragtegy has no error.. it should work just fine..